# Manifolds with Boundary - I think I misunderstood the definition of boundary points, because I found a contradiction

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

The following definitions are from the 2nd edition of John Lee's "Introduction to
Smooth Manifolds", page 25.

**Definition 1**

> We will call a chart $(U,\phi)$ an **interior
> chart** if $\phi(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ and a **boundary chart** if $\phi(U)$ is an open subset
> of $\mathbf{H}^n$ such that $\phi(U)\cap\partial\mathbf{H}^n$ is not empty.

**Definition 2**

> A point $p\in M$ is called an **interior point** of $M$ if it is in the domain of some
> interior chart. It is a **boundary point** of $M$ if it is in the domain of a boundary chart
> that sends $p$ to $\partial\mathbf{H}^n$.

Consider the manifold $S^1$. The inverses of
\begin{align}
[0,\pi)&\to S^1\\
x&\mapsto\mathrm{e}^{ix}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
[0,\pi)&\to S^1\\
x&\mapsto-\mathrm{e}^{ix}
\end{align}
are boundary charts and according to the definition above, $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are boundary points of $S^1$.
But the inverse of
\begin{align}
(-\pi,\pi)&\to S^1\\
x&\mapsto\mathrm{e}^{ix}
\end{align}
is an interior chart (smoothly compatible with the other two charts) and $(1,0)$ turns out to be an interior point.

Comment: the sphere is not a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @Zest According to John Lee's definition of manifolds with boundary, all smooth manifolds are manifolds with boundary.

Comment: @Zest Also from page 25: An n-dimensional topological manifold with boundary is a second-countable
Hausdorff space M in which every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic either
to an open subset of $R^n$ or to a (relatively) open subset of $H^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p : [0, \pi) \to S^1,~~ x \mapsto e^{ix}$ be one of the parametrizations you chose, and let $U := p([0, \pi)) \subset S^1$.

Then $p^{-1} : U \to [0, \pi)$ is not a chart because $U$ is not an open subset of $S^1$.